# Using Entity Framework with Multiple Databases and Providers in the Same Project (SQL Server and MySql)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, mysql-connector

### Background:

I have an application (both web forms and console) that easily accesses multiple SQL Server databases using Entity Framework code first with no problems. I can switch back and forth between contexts with no errors. Now I'm trying to add in a new MySql database (different provider), but if I switch from one context to another, I get the below error message:

### Error:

> The default DbConfiguration instance was used by the Entity Framework
>   before the 'MySqlEFConfiguration' type was discovered. An instance of
>   'MySqlEFConfiguration' must be set at application start before using
>   any Entity Framework features or must be registered in the
>   application's config file. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883 for more information.

I've seen solutions that recommend adding the "codeConfigurationType" attribute to the entityFramework node in the web.config to specify my MySql assembly, but this won't work since I'm targeting multiple databases with multiple providers.

The Microsoft support article seems to hint at creating my own custom DbConfiguration file, but I already have one: MySql.Data.Entity.mySqlEFConfiguration, and I've decorated my DbContext with it accordingly:

```sql
   [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class MySqlDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public MySqlDBContext() : base("MySqlDBContext")
        {

        }
    }
...
```

Here's how I have my web.config set up:

```sql
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>        
    <add name="FirstSQLServerDBContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=SQLServerName;MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Database=FirstSQLDB; User ID=SQLUsername;Password=SqlPassword; Encrypt=true;" />
    <add name="SecondSQLServerDBContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=SQLServerName;MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Database=SecondSQLDB; User ID=SQLUsername;Password=SqlPassword; Encrypt=true;" />
    <add name="MySqlDBContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=MySqlServerName; port=3306;database=MySqlDB; uid=MySqlUsername; password=MySqlPassword;" />    
  </connectionStrings>
```

### Question:

It doesn't seem like there's any way to do this using config file configuration since I'm limited to a single  entry. So how can I specify the provider when switching contexts? I imagine there's something I'm missing in each DbContext's constructor to explicitly state which provider to use? For the record, I'm receiving the same error message in both a console application and a web forms application.

### Update: Additional Info

- (8/21/19) It seems to work okay if I disable MultipleActiveResultSets (MARS) on the SQLServer data sources, though this isn't an ideal solution since I've written my code to take advantage of MARS.
- (8/22/19) Actually that wouldn't have solved it. It would have just gone on to the next problem. There can only be one DbConfiguration per application, so the solution will likely involve writing one that works with both providers... I've submitted a support request with my MSDN subscription to see if they have any additional insight...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of Microsoft, I finally figured it out. Hopefully this helps someone else out there. I had to create my own class inheriting from DbConfiguration

```
public class MyCustomSQLDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyCustomSQLDbConfiguration()
    {
        SetExecutionStrategy("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", () => new MySqlExecutionStrategy());
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new LocalDbConnectionFactory("mssqllocaldb"));
    }
}
```

Then decorate my MySqlDBContext accordingly:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyCustomSQLDbConfiguration))]
public class MySqlDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MySqlDBContext() : base("MySqlDBContext")
    {

    }
 }
```

And then finally (and importantly), explicitly set this when I run the application. In the case of a console app, at the beginning of Program.Main, or in a web application, on Application_Start:

```
DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MyCustomSQLDbConfiguration());
```

Comment: It seems you have two DbContext classes, right? If Yes then how do you switch between them? If No then i think i couldn't get your solution, would you please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a partial class:

```
 public partial class MySqlDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public MySqlDBContext(string FirstSQLServerDBContext)
            : base(configmanager.connectionstrings(FirstSQLServerDBContext)...)
        {
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. That didn't quite do it... I'm thinking it needs to be something in the constructor that reaffirms which provider to use, but I can't find any such guidance in the documentation from Microsoft or really anywhere...

Comment: you didn't try changing the Context.cs right?  just in a different class (like a data repo or facade) in the same namespace, and add the partial class and constructor with connection string.  I have multipleactiveresultsets = true.  My providername is system.data.entityClient though, since I'm using edmx.

Comment: Then I get the following:

"Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'MySqlDbContext': another partial declaration of this type exists

Answer (score 1):

Custom DbConfiguration has also worked for me.
Alternatively, I have seen it worked successfully using DbContext with DbConnection constructor without using any DbConfiguration attribute.

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MssqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
using (var mssqlDbContext = new MSSQLDbContext(sqlConnection, true))
{
   //...
}

using (var mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MysqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
using (var mySQLDbContext = new MySQLDbContext(mySqlConnection, true))
{
   //...
}
```

and system.data section in config is as below.

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
           type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=8.0.24.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

I can see results retrieved from both data contexts (MSSQL Compact and MySQL).

Comment: Hi, can you add links to help understand your solution?

Comment: I investigated further and checked decompiled source of MySqlEFConfiguration class. I strongly assume that there is some configuration in official MySql.Data.EntityFramework.MySqlEFConfiguration class ctor which causes this problem. However if you want to use all features of mysql with EF (migrations etc.), you should set configuration as this class did.

Comment: You can separate your DbConfiguration for another project using web.config (or app.config) file and setting codeConfigurationType of entityframework xml node. So I use official configuration class as attribute for migration project , however I use my custom configuration class for main web project.

Comment: Hi, you can read "Moving DbConfiguration" titled section in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/code-based. It explains how to set configuration in config file. So you should set your config of app like this with your custom dbconfiguration type if you want to use both multiple context.